# How to get substring out of string in swift ui?

Tags: arrays, swift, string

In UIKit I used the same method to get only one part out of a long string and there it worked. However it dosen't work in swift ui app. I have wondered if it might be that it is not a string, but something else. Does anyone know a better solution to only get a short substring out of the long text?

```
let url = URL(string: "https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/spa.pl?syear=2020&smonth=1&sday=1&eyear=2020&emonth=1&eday=1&otype=0&step=60&stepunit=1&hr=12&min=0&sec=0&latitude=39.743&longitude=-105.178&timezone=-7.0&elev=1829&press=835&temp=10&dut1=0.0&deltat=64.797&azmrot=180&slope=0&refract=0.5667&field=0")

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var html = try! String(contentsOf: url!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
    
    let leftSideOfTheValue = "1/1/2020,0:00:00,"
    
    let rightSideOfTheValue = "1/1/2020,1:00:00,"
    
    guard let leftRange = html.range(of: leftSideOfTheValue) else {
        print("cant find left range")
        return
    }
    
    guard let rightRange = html.range(of: rightSideOfTheValue) else {
        print("cant find right range")
        return
    
    let rangeOfTheValue = leftRange.upperBound..<rightRange.lowerBound
    
    let elevationInfo = (html[rangeOfTheValue])
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(elevationInfo)
                
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned in your previous question the output is CSV, it’s **not HMTL**.Each line is a record, the fields are separated by comma, and the first line contains the field names. And never get data from a remote URL with synchronous API like `String(contentsOf`. That’s horrible practice.

Comment: What does *“it dosen't work in swift ui app”* mean exactly? Does it not compile? What are the error messages? Or do you get a wrong result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possible solution (Using function):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let url = URL(string: "https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/spa.pl?syear=2020&smonth=1&sday=1&eyear=2020&emonth=1&eday=1&otype=0&step=60&stepunit=1&hr=12&min=0&sec=0&latitude=39.743&longitude=-105.178&timezone=-7.0&elev=1829&press=835&temp=10&dut1=0.0&deltat=64.797&azmrot=180&slope=0&refract=0.5667&field=0")
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.getSubstring(from: url))
        
    }
    
    private func getSubstring(from url: URL?) -> String {
        guard let url = url else {
            return ""
        }
        
        let html = try! String(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
        let leftSideOfTheValue = "1/1/2020,0:00:00,"
        
        let rightSideOfTheValue = "1/1/2020,1:00:00,"
        
        guard let leftRange = html.range(of: leftSideOfTheValue) else {
            print("cant find left range")
            return ""
        }
        
        guard let rightRange = html.range(of: rightSideOfTheValue) else {
            print("cant find right range")
            return ""
        }
        
        let rangeOfTheValue = leftRange.upperBound..<rightRange.lowerBound
        
        return String(html[rangeOfTheValue])
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the question author and to future readers of this Q&A) if they *explain* the problem and the solution ...

Comment: You shouldn't be using `String(contentsOf:` (or any of the similarly named functions such as `Data(contentsOf:)`) to load data from a remote URL. That function was designed to load data from a local URL synchronously. Using it to load data from a remote URL will block your UI for a significant amount of time. You should use the proper `URLSession.DataTask` functions to load remote data asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, you are right @MartinR, but the problem is how to explain him? because I need to explain the whole struct part, from zero. so from my point, he needs only a solution otherwise he first started learning SwiftUI from var declarion.

Comment: The first problem is that the question itself is unclear, *“it dosen't work in swift ui”* is a useless problem description. So the proper action would be to ask for clarification, and possibly vote/flag as unclear until the question is improved.

Comment: @DávidPásztor. I just answer the question of how he used UIKit code in SwiftUI. So I never touched his logic code. it's not a part of the question.

Comment: @RajaKishan even if it's not part of the question, such bad practices should not be encouraged by keeping them in an answer. When writing an answer, you should aim to providing high quality code that will be usable for future readers. This contains fixing major problems with OP's code even if said problem isn't part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not particularly related to Swift UI, the following solution is general.

As I said a few times the received data is CSV (comma separated values), each line is a record, the fields are separated by comma.

To parse the string first create a custom struct

```
struct ZenithData {
    let date : Date
    let angle : Double
}
```

and a data source array

```
var zenithData = [ZenithData]()
```

then load the data asynchronously with `URLSession`, split the text into lines, split the lines into fields, join the date and time parts and convert it into `Date` and populate the array.

Note: The exact date format is ambiguous. The format could be also `d/M/yyyy`

```
let url = URL(string: "https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/spa.pl?syear=2020&smonth=1&sday=1&eyear=2020&emonth=1&eday=1&otype=0&step=60&stepunit=1&hr=12&min=0&sec=0&latitude=39.743&longitude=-105.178&timezone=-7.0&elev=1829&press=835&temp=10&dut1=0.0&deltat=64.797&azmrot=180&slope=0&refract=0.5667&field=0")

let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss"
    
    let lines = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
    for i in 1..<lines.count { // first line is dropped
        let fields = lines[i].components(separatedBy: ",")
        if fields.count != 3 { continue }
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: fields[0] + " " + fields[1])!
        let angle = Double(fields[2])!
        zenithData.append(ZenithData(date: date, angle: angle))
    }
    print(zenithData)
}
dataTask.resume()
```