# How do I fix error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"?

Tags: swift, csv

The url is passed from the content view into the second view. And then the csv content from the website is passed into an array. When I enter print(html2) in the `func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {` it prints the whole array in the console.

However I only want specific parts of the array. As u see, I want to add these values into a path. But when I try to only get one value out of the array(and turn it into a Double) I get the Error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" I don't understand why this happens, since the whole array is longer than 3.

Edit: NIL is also printed in the console (from `guard let url = url else { return ["Nil"] }`, maybe this has something to do with it.

This is the website, im getting the csv file from: https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/spa.pl?syear=2020&smonth=2&sday=1&eyear=2020&emonth=2&eday=1&otype=0&step=60&stepunit=1&hr=12&min=0&sec=0&latitude=59&longitude=10.757933&timezone=1.0&elev=53&press=835&temp=10&dut1=0.0&deltat=64.797&azmrot=180&slope=0&refract=0.5667&field=0

The printed array in the console looks like this:

["Date (M/D/YYYY),Time (H:MM:SS),Topocentric zenith angle", "137.953123", "137.960600", "135.198176", "130.197954", "123.688949", "116.325934", "108.624973", "101.000252", "93.815722", "87.217417", "82.082535", "78.352650", "76.383830", "76.356635", "78.273202", "81.956771", "87.057240", "93.615330", "100.772681", "108.374905", "116.056945", "123.404211", "129.901657", "134.897752"]

This is my code:

```
func loadData(from url: URL?) -> Array<String> {
    guard let url = url else {
        return ["Nil"]
    }

    let html = try! String(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    
    let parsedCSV: [String] = html.components(
        separatedBy: "00:00,"
    ).map{ $0.components(separatedBy: "\n")[0] }
    return parsedCSV
}

struct elevationFunction: Shape {
    
    var url1: URL?
    
    var html2: Array<String> { loadData(from: self.url1) }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        var path = Path()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: (125 - (90-Double(html2[3])!)))) // the error is here
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 120, y: (125 - (90-45))))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: (125 - (90-Double(html2[3])!)))) // and here

        var scale = (rect.height / 350) * (9/10)
        var xOffset = (rect.width / 6)
        var yOffset = (rect.height / 6.5)

        return path.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)).applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: xOffset, y: yOffset))


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array indices are zero-based, the third element is index 2

```
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: (125 - (90-Double(html2[2])!))))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 120, y: (125 - (90-45))))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: (125 - (90-Double(html2[2])!))))
```

I have a [Déjà Vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664174/how-to-get-substring-out-of-string-in-swift-ui): I remember this code and I remember having encouraged you to use `URLSession` and to parse the CSV data into a struct.

Run this in a Playground

```
struct Zenith {
    let date : Date
    let angle : Double
}


func loadData(from urlString: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[Zenith],Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        completion( .failure(URLError(.badURL))); return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {  data, _, error in
        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale (identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss"
        let csvLines = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!.components(separatedBy: .newlines).dropFirst()
        let zenithData = csvLines.compactMap { line -> Zenith? in
            let components = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
            guard components.count == 3 else { return nil }
            guard let date = formatter.date(from: components[0] + " " + components[1]),
                let angle = Double(components[2]) else { return nil }
            return Zenith(date: date, angle: angle)
        }
        completion(.success(zenithData))
    }
    task.resume()
}

let urlString = "https://midcdmz.nrel.gov/apps/spa.pl?syear=2020&smonth=2&sday=1&eyear=2020&emonth=2&eday=1&otype=0&step=60&stepunit=1&hr=12&min=0&sec=0&latitude=59&longitude=10.757933&timezone=1.0&elev=53&press=835&temp=10&dut1=0.0&deltat=64.797&azmrot=180&slope=0&refract=0.5667&field=0"

loadData(from: urlString) { result in
    switch result {

    case .success(let data): print(data)
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

You have to remove the `loadData()` call from `Shape` anyway if you load the data asynchronously.

Comment: if you don't set the date formatter's locale it will use the device's calendar which is VERY error prone